# Emberjs starter-kit test fails

Tags: ember.js

I have installed the Emberjs starter-kit from Github: [ember-starter-kit](https://github.com/emberjs/starter-kit)

And placed it [here](http://fertilemedia.com/playground/ember/starterkit/index.html)

And everything seems to work fine, but when I try the testing environment, by using the ?test command, it seems to [fail](http://fertilemedia.com/playground/ember/starterkit/index.html?test)

This all happens while I haven't made any changes to the starter-kit.

The only thing I can think of that might cause problems with the testing is the fact that fertilemedia.com has mod_rewrite (a .htaccess) at root level, but I could not find anything online about mod_rewrite interfering with the emberjs tests.

I've also tried adding:

```
App.Router.reopen({
  rootURL: '/playground/ember/starterkit/'
});
```

But this does not seem to have any effect.

Since I've made no changes to the starter-kit, and the non-test page seems to work fine, what am I doing wrong?